# UIPrintPageRenderer issue : generate pdf when loading multiple css files in HTML file

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiprintpagerenderer

I'm using [BNHtmlPdfKit](https://github.com/brentnycum/BNHtmlPdfKit) to generate pdf file from html template.
This lib has a UIWebView, it will load html string.

Then it use UIPrintPageRenderer to generate pdf file.

In HTML file, I have imported 2 css files like below :

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Currently, the rendered pdf file has only css style of the bootstrap.css file.

However, I tried to add important! property for each item in style.css, the pdf could display css style of style.css file.

```
#myContent {
    background-color: lightblue !important;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
    color: red !important;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Anyone has been able to generate pdf using multiple css file and without using !important property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux is that `bootstrap.css` overwrites your style via `@media print { }` rules and `UIPrintPageRenderer` **prints** the content to PDF file.